# Need to set an association on a User with Devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

We're using devise for registrations and authentication.  We have companies that have many users and users have one company.  We'd like to, when a user signs up, extract the domain from their email, use it to identify their company, and associate this new user with that company before the user gets created.

We've tried hijacking the create method in the RegistrationController:

```
def create
  super do |user|
    company = Registrations::FindcompanyByEmailDomain.call(user.email)
    if company
      user.company = company
      user.save
    end
  end
end
```

But this is not ideal. It seems to affect the redirects after create and I'd rather do this another way. Any suggestions?

Here are our attempts to override the Devise paths after a user is created:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  go_to_a_path # doesn't work
end

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  go_to_another_path #also doesn't work
end
```

We've also tried using 
    before_create :get_company

```
def get_company
  self.company = FindCompanyByDomain(domain)
end
```

and the same with `before_save` in the user model with some magic up update the `user.company`, but both hooks get passed over (`binding.pry` gets ignored) when the Devise controller does its thing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show exactly what you did in the callback?

Comment: yup, updated again with that code.

Comment: You could try overriding `save`, and checking if the user is `persisted?`, or not. If you'd rather not have the overhead of checking this each time a user is saved, and your users are `confirmable`, then perhaps override `confirm!`. This is frequently used to send out welcome emails to newly confirmed users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we overrode a method in the devise controller:

```
      # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

We were struggling because the controller would try to save the user before doing anything else, so the only opportunity we had to change this was to create our own `build_resource` method:

```
def build_resource(user_params)
  super.tap do |user|
    user.company = Registrations::FindCompanyByEmailDomain.call(user.email)
  end
end
```

This allows us to pass the user model with the associated company to super and solves our problem.